# IBM DB2 ODBC drivers - DB2COPY1 or IBMDBCL1 for a Power BI connection?

Tags: powerbi, db2, odbc, driver

I'm working in a team of people who connect Power BI to a db2 database in order to create reports. However, people are doing this via two different drivers, and this is creating compatibility problems when refreshing each others' reports.

I want to get everyone using the same driver for consistency & compatibility, but I'm not sure which is best for purpose.

The two drivers are:

- IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER DB2COPY1 (appears under the 'System DSN' tab in ODBC Data Source Administrator)
- IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER IBMDBCL1 (appears under the 'User DSN' tab in ODBC Data Source Administrator)

Does anyone know what the practical difference is between the two please? And is either considered industry standard for connecting to db2 from Power BI? I don't really know anything about what the drivers are doing behind the scenes. I had a look at [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-odbc-cli-driver-download-and-installation-information) but couldn't find anything explaining why you might choose one over another.

Comment: What you are showing are not drivers, these are ODBC data sources; system and user data sources differ in [who can use them](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-a-dsn-data-source-name-ae9a0c76-22fc-8a30-606e-2436fe26e89f).

Comment: Define"compatibility problems"? Precision matters. Likely causes: (1) Db2-driver-versions, (2) Db2-driver config,  (3) user-authorization. For (1) get plain text output of `db2level` command on each workstation, add to question. Ensure you are on the latest version+fixpack of the IBM supplied Db2 driver. For (2) determine differences in either the connection-strings or the contents of `db2cli.ini` or `db2dsdriver.cfg` on different workstations, and for (3) learn which userids have exactly which symptoms for different combinations of (1) and (2).

Comment: @mustaccio: If I look in ODBC Data Source Administrator they are listed as drivers though? E.g. Driver = IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER IBMDBCL1.

Comment: @mao: The main problem is that if user A creates a report using one of the drivers and publishes it to the Power BI service, user B cannot schedule it to auto-refresh unless they also have that driver installed. The only way they can refresh the report is to manually open it in the desktop version of Power BI, refresh it there, and republish it. This is important because my organisation is currently using personal data gateways to schedule auto-refresh, so if someone's on holiday/sick and unconnected from our network someone else needs to take over the report.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same:

[image]

The fact that you have two of them doesn't mean you have compatibility problems.

Keep going like that, you are good to go.

> Does anyone know what the practical difference is between the two
> please?

Yes, one is for your User and the other is for the whole System.

> And is either considered industry standard for connecting to db2 from
> Power BI?

Yes, you should use the standard connection that Power BI provides [out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/ibmdb2database)

[image]