# Which driver to connect Power BI to DB2?

Tags: powerbi, db2, odbc, driver

I have an odd question on connecting Power BI to a DB2 database.

I currently seem to have three similar drivers installed on my computer. If I look in ODBC data source administrator under the drivers tab I can see that they have the following names:

- IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER
- IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1
- IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - IBMDBCL1

The first and third driver have the same version number (10.05.00.420). The second has a different version number (11.01.4041.600).

All three use the same DLL file (DB2CLIO.DLL).

All three seem to be able to connect Power BI to DB2 when used as a DSN, so I'm trying to establish which I should be using.

I want to know if these are different versions of the same driver which have been given different names during installation, or whether they are different drivers. And if they are different drivers, what is the difference?

Any advice would be appreciated please!

Comment: Seemt to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195440/ibm-db2-odbc-drivers-db2copy1-or-ibmdbcl1-for-a-power-bi-connection

Answer (score 0):

[From IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=windows-data-server-client-connectivity-using-multiple-copies): "The IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI contains the copy name as part of the driver name. The default driver, IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER, is set to the default IBM database client interface copy. The name of the driver for each installation is "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - Copy Name"."

So if you select the first one, IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER, ODBC will check with your settings and use the default driver copy on your computer, which will be one of the other 2 drivers. You set the default by using the [**db2swtch** command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=sc-db2swtch-switch-default-db2-copy-database-client-interface-copy).

The driver version should be tied to the version of DB2. Check with your DBA or just check with the [right SQL for your DB2 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version) (Windows, Linux, Z/OS, etc.).